# Can't update multiple records in a collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]
```

and here is the code:

```
Template.notifications.events({
   'click a.clearAll':function(event){
    console.log("hey");
    Notifications.update({{userId:Meteor.userId()},{$set:{read:true}},{multi:true});
 }
})
```

I've also set update permissions:

```
Notifications.allow({
  insert: function(){
 return true;
 },
 update: function(){
return true;
 }
});
```

Why is it not letting me update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is because you are making the update from the client, this is considered **'untrusted code'** by the server.

Unless you have not yet removed the insecure package and not made any permission rules, it would otherwise work. I suggest it a good practice to always remove the insecure package by `meteor remove insecure` and make method/calls to execute server functions instigated by the client.

You need to make a ['call'](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) from the client to the server, and execute the update command inside the [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) function.

client:

```
Template.notifications.events({
   'click a.clearAll':function(event){
        Meteor.call('updateDocs',
            function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('done');
                }
            });
    }
});
```

server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateDocs: function() {
        var userId = this.userId
        if (userId) {
            Notifications.update({{userId: userId},{$set:{read:true}},{multi:true});
        }
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@meteorBuzz is correct. If you still wish to update from the client you can do so using `forEach`:

```
Notifications.find({ userId:Meteor.userId() }).forEach(function(n){
  Notifications.update({ _id: n._id },{$set:{ read:true }});
});
```